# which html tag to use for a custom select input

Tags: html, reactjs

I am building a custom select on react. I know it is not the best idea in terms of usability and compatibility, but I have to do it because product requirements.

My first approach uses a button to simulate the select input, and for the dropdown I use an absolute positioned div with a list of buttons. The reason why I choose button for the options in the list is because they have several interesting features out of the box:

- they are tab-focusable by default
- they can be activated by the keyboard (enter/space)
- they have disabled and focus states
- they have proper pointer events

Roughly it looks something like this:

```js
<div class="relative-wrapper">
  <button class="select">{selected_value}</button>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="option" role="option" aria-selected={someFlag}>{value1}</button>
    <button class="option" role="option" aria-selected={someFlag}>{value2}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But investigating other implementations I see several ones (for example Material-ui) using `ul` and `li` instead with a bunch of attributes and styles to make them look and behave like buttons. That made me guess if my choose if the correct one or If it would be better to use other html tags like the mentioned `ul` and `li`. Is there any inherent problem in using buttons or any advantage in using lists?

Answer (score 0):

Lists structure the group of elements together. Buttons are interactive by default.

There's no reason not to use both.

```
<ul>
    <li> <button> ... </button> </li>
    <li> <button> ... </button> </li>
</ul>
```

Although I'd lean towards radio buttons with labels instead of buttons for the options since they come with built-in "Select one" logic.

Comment: Since this is a react component, the added select-one logic is not very valuable for me. In fact maybe in the near future we have to implement multiple select. Will the list structure have any different treatment by screen readers? after all, the div is also grouping the buttons

Comment: The select one logic can also be exposed by assistive technology so the user knows they are selecting one. If you want to change to select multiple, then switching to checkboxes becomes trivial. Lists are announced as lists in screen readers.